# How to control access to class members for multiple classes (i.e. an access modifier with the scope folder/namespace)?

Tags: typescript, access-modifiers

In Java, protected class members can be accesses by any class within the same package but not by classes outside. How can I accomplish this in Typescript?

E.g. I want a class Foo and a class Foo2 (which does not inherit from Foo) that can access each others "protected" members. But a class Bar outside of the scope (e.g. my folder or a namespace) should only be able to access the public members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There currently is no package [`internal`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5228) access modifier in TS yet. A possible workaround is to use an [escape hatch](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12111#issuecomment-259568490) for `protected`/`private` class member access:

```
class Foo { 
  protected f1 = "f1" 
}

class Foo2 {
  protected f2 = "f2"

  public doSomething(foo: Foo) {
    foo["f1"] // this works
  }
}
```

You can access a `protected` member from another class via property access with bracket notation.

Yeah, that works. This workaround will still hide `protected` members from other classes in general. Assuming `Foo` and `Foo2` are in the same package and therefore have stronger coupling, they can better afford to know implementation details of the other class like a protected property name. So this hatch should be valid from an architecture perspective as well.

If more safety is needed, you could create extra `Foo` and `Foo2` types to be consumed with the public API of your sub package, so a client isn't even aware of the given class:

```
class Foo implements FooPublic {
  publicProp = 42
  protected foo = "foo"
}

interface FooPublic {
  publicProp: number // only publicProp is visible to client
}
```

Additional note: There is also an ESLint rule called [`import/no-internal-modules`](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/no-internal-modules.md), that enforces, a client cannot `import` your real class from a sub-module.